# Meaning of "delocalized campus"

Tags: graduate-admissions, application

While filling a PhD application for a European university, I came across a field  that needed to be filled. The field - to be filled by 'Yes or No' -  asked if my master's or bachelor's universities are 'delocalized campuses'. This is the first time I have come across this term. I am not a native English speaker.

What does 'delocalized campus' mean?

Comment: I *guess* it means if your studies were performed on a campus away from the central university.  For example, my PhD was at Kiruna Campus of [Luleå University of Technology](http://www.ltu.se).  Why they would care is another question. (*Note: I'm not sure, hence I post this as a comment, rather than as an answer*).

Comment: Another possibility is that it might mean distance learning, for example the Open University.  I did a web search, and https://it4bi-dc.ulb.ac.be/emundus/images/stories/provided_documents/it4bi-dc_application_manual.pdf defines it to mean "an international campus abroad from your home university" (which is a special case of gerrit's definition).  However, I have no idea whether that meaning applies to your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the link below.
http://www.business-school-pgsm.com/delocalized-programs.html

for delocalized institutions….understand them as partner institutions.

Oxford Dictionary:delocalize
verb
[with object]
detach or remove (something) from a particular place or location, or from local limitations:
(as adjective delocalized)

Merriam-Webster: Delocalize:
to free from the limitations of locality; specifically :  to remove (a charge or charge carrier) from a particular position

Definitions aside:

Some smaller institutions/colleges have partnerships with big colleges/universities to confer degrees. For instance if you attended an institute that offers degrees with a bigger universities' name, then Yes your diplomas were obtained from a delocalized campus.

I attended a university with more than 7 campuses. 
So if you attended any of the six campuses apart from the main campus or if you took your studies online; then Yes, your bachelors/masters degrees were obtained from a delocalized campus.

Comment: For a state like PA I can see how this works since State College is clearly the main campus. How does it work for a state like CA? Is UCLA or UC-Berkeley a delocalised campus?

Comment: @StrongBad A very old post, but no, I would never describe constituent members of the UC system as "delocalized." Dunno about PA.